# Running RMCL (Lisp) on WIndows

Tags: windows, lisp, mcl

Is there ANY way to run RMCL/MCL on Windows?  I have a lot of code written for RMCL that needs to interact with a Windows program. Right now we do this by communicating over the network, but that seems to be too slow.

I tried PearPC several months ago, but that didn't seem to work. Are there any other options?

Comment: Is the code portable Common Lisp? There are other CL compilers for Windows...

Comment: Do you use some RMCL-specific code?  If your code is portable or could be made portable, you could try some other CL implementation that is available for Windows, e.g. CLisp or SBCL.

Comment: The RMCL code uses graphics libraries, which are specific to Mac. So I'd either need a Mac OS emulator that can run RMCL, or a version of CL for Windows that uses the same syntax for drawing graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a different Common Lisp runtime for Windows? RMCL is a Common Lisp. That means theoretically there's a standard that all of the Common Lisps follow.

That said, if you're taking advantage of RMCL's access to Carbon, then you're unlikely to ever get your program to work on Windows without a lot of porting.

Answer (score 1):

[Clozure](http://www.clozure.com/clozurecl.html) is an open-source fork of Macintosh Common Lisp (aka Coral Common Lisp).  It runs on a number of platforms, including Windows.